# Using a Template with Data Bindings in Multiple Components

Tags: angular, angular2-template

*Edit: I solved this problem below. If you're looking for a way to reuse a template that depends on its parent component's service(s) for its data bindings, read on. Or just jump to the TL;DR portion of the answer.*

I have a block of markup that I use as a template in three separate components. I want to create a template from this markup so I can just drop it into these components using its selector as an element tag.

Below is one of the three components that use this block of markup.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Thread } from './thread';
import { FeaturedThreadsService } from './featured-threads.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'featured-threads',
    templateUrl: 'featured-threads.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['featured-threads.component.css'],
    providers: [ FeaturedThreadsService ]
})

export class FeaturedThreadsComponent implements OnInit { 

    threads: Thread[];

    constructor(private featuredThreadsService: FeaturedThreadsService) { }

    getThreads(): void {
        this.threads = this.featuredThreadsService.getThreads();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getThreads();
    }
}
```

`featured-thread.component.html` is below.

```
<div *ngFor="let thread of threads" class="thread-tile">
<div class="description col-sm-12">
    <div class="author-card col-sm-2">
        <div>
            <img src="{{thread.profileImage}}" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="awards">
            <span class="author-card-renown">
                {{thread.renown}}
            </span>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li style="padding: 2px" *ngIf="thread.numBlue > 0"><img src="./assets/blue.png"> {{thread.numBlue}}</li>                   
                <li style="padding: 2px" *ngIf="thread.numGold > 0"><img src="./assets/gold.png"> {{thread.numGold}}</li>
                <li style="padding: 2px" *ngIf="thread.numSilver > 0"><img src="./assets/silver.png"> {{thread.numSilver}}</li>         
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title col-sm-10">{{thread.title}}</div> 
    <div class="author-date col-sm-10">
        by <a href="#">{{thread.author}}</a> on {{ (thread.date | amFromUnix) | amDateFormat:'MM/DD/YY'}} at {{ (thread.date | amFromUnix) | amDateFormat:'hh:mmA'}}
    </div>
    <div class="participants col-sm-10">
        Participants: 
        <ul *ngFor="let participant of thread.participants" class="participant list-inline">
            <li><a href="#">{{participant}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tags-container col-sm-10">
        <div *ngFor="let tag of thread.tags">
            <div class="tag">{{tag}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thread-metrics">
        {{thread.numPosts}} posts  {{thread.numFlags}} flags  {{thread.numParticipants}} participants  {{thread.numContributors}} contributors
    </div>
</div>
```

Each of the three components use the same markup as their templates. The only difference is that their respective services return different data.

I've created a component to drop the markup into each of the components's templates, so if I need to edit the markup I only edit it once. I used the `@Input` decorator to pass data from parent to child and imported the components' services.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Thread } from './thread';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'thread',
    templateUrl: 'thread.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['thread.component.css']
})

export class ThreadComponent {

    @Input() threads: Thread[];
}
```

Then I drop the template into the components and bind the child's iteration instances to its parent's properties.

```
<thread *ngFor="let thread of threads" [threads]="threads"></thread>
```

*Edit: Here I thought the iteration somehow iterated over the data bindings within the child template. It turns out that this line was the problem. See my answer for details.*

Only `featured-threads.component` behaves as desired. It displays correctly using the data pulled from the `featured-threads.service`'s logic. The other two components simply list all threads, bypassing the logic of their parents' services.

Why is this happening? I'm also open to any approach that achieves the same outcome of not having to repeat the same markup in three separate components' templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<thread *ngFor="let thread of threads" [threads]="threads"></thread>
```

This `ngFor` expression was returning query results for every data binding within the child template. This gave me the impression that I was returning the whole database and that the services' logic wasn't being used. I was able to verify that the services' logic was being used simply by logging to the console within the services' logic (duh), which led me to look more closely. I simply removed the `ngFor` expression and was left with this

```
<thread [threads]="threads"></thread>
```

This binds the parent component's `threads` property to `threads` in the child template's `ngFor="let thread in threads"` expression.

**TL;DR:**

If you want to use a template in multiple components when the template contains data bindings to and/or from its components, simply use the `@Input` decorator in the template's component declaration:

`@Input() foo: Foo;`

When you drop the template into a parent component using the property binding shown below, the parent component's property `bar` is bound to the template's component Input `foo`:

`<foo-bar [foo]="bar"></foo-bar>`